# Does python's ctypes c_char work for windows 64?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to load a process list, and it functions correctly on 32bit python.  However, on 64bit, I can't get the process name to list.  The code is below.  If I change szExeFile's structure from a c_char, to c_int or long, the process list enumerate, but I have no way of seeing what pid belongs to what exe.  How can I get this to function on x64?

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
import sys


# const variable
# Establish rights and basic options needed for all process declartion / iteration
TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 2
STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000
SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000
PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SYNCHRONIZE | 0xFFF)
TH32CS_SNAPMODULE = 0x00000008
TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD = 0x00000004

##  Create object definitions to story information in
class PROCESSENTRY32(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ( 'dwSize' , c_uint ) , 
                 ( 'cntUsage' , c_uint) ,
                 ( 'th32ProcessID' , c_uint) ,
                 ( 'th32DefaultHeapID' , c_uint) ,
                 ( 'th32ModuleID' , c_uint) ,
                 ( 'cntThreads' , c_uint) ,
                 ( 'th32ParentProcessID' , c_uint) ,
                 ( 'pcPriClassBase' , c_long) ,
                 ( 'dwFlags' , c_uint) ,
                 ( 'szExeFile' , c_char * 260 ) ]

CreateToolhelp32Snapshot= windll.kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
Process32First = windll.kernel32.Process32First
Process32Next = windll.kernel32.Process32Next
GetLastError = windll.kernel32.GetLastError
OpenProcess = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
GetPriorityClass = windll.kernel32.GetPriorityClass
CloseHandle = windll.kernel32.CloseHandle

try:
    hProcessSnap = c_void_p(0)
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS , 0 )
    pe32 = PROCESSENTRY32()
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 )
    ret = Process32First( hProcessSnap , pointer( pe32 ) )
    global PROGPid
    PROGPid=False
    while ret:
        print pe32.dwSize,pe32.cntUsage,pe32.th32ProcessID,pe32.th32DefaultHeapID,pe32.th32ModuleID,pe32.cntThreads,pe32.th32ParentProcessID,pe32.pcPriClassBase,pe32.dwFlags,pe32.szExeFile
        hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS , 0 , pe32.th32ProcessID )
        dwPriorityClass = GetPriorityClass( hProcess )
        if dwPriorityClass == 0 :
            CloseHandle( hProcess )
        PROGPid=pe32.th32ProcessID
        ret = Process32Next( hProcessSnap, pointer(pe32) )
        print PROGPid
    CloseHandle ( hProcessSnap )

except:
    print "Error in ListProcessPid"
```

Comment: [`[p for p in psutil.process_iter()]`](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) creates a process list. `psutil` currently supports Linux, Windows, OSX and FreeBSD, both 32-bit and 64-bit, with Python versions from 2.4 to 3.3 by using a single code base. Pypy is also known to work.

Comment: the distribution in this environment doesn't have psutils, and I can't deploy it.

Comment: Does [`EnumProcesses`](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/trunk/psutil/arch/mswindows/process_info.c#107) work on x64?

Comment: It does, and so does wmi indexing.  The reason for using the kernel32 vs. paspi was to also then find the base memory offset of a program's dll.  Char is also used on the "firstmodule" / "lastmodule" functions and produces the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [PROCESSENTRY32 structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is wrong. This works for me:

```
class PROCESSENTRY32(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ( 'dwSize' , DWORD ) ,
                 ( 'cntUsage' , DWORD) ,
                 ( 'th32ProcessID' , DWORD) ,
                 ( 'th32DefaultHeapID' , POINTER(ULONG)) ,
                 ( 'th32ModuleID' , DWORD) ,
                 ( 'cntThreads' , DWORD) ,
                 ( 'th32ParentProcessID' , DWORD) ,
                 ( 'pcPriClassBase' , LONG) ,
                 ( 'dwFlags' , DWORD) ,
                 ( 'szExeFile' , c_char * 260 ) ]
```

Comment: Can you tell me where / how you came up with this structure?  I'm trying to do the same thing with MODULEENTRY32 and running into a similar issue.

Comment: These structures are documented at the MSDN, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: yeah i used the structure listed there with a failure.  Can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763459/how-to-enumerate-modules-in-python-64bit