# Finding the baseaddress of a running process

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, python-3.2

Ive got the following code:

```
import subprocess
from ctypes import *

#-Part where I get the PID and declare all variables-#

OpenProcess = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
ReadProcessMemory = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory

processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, PID)

ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, bufferSize, byref(bytesRead))
```

All this is working flawless, but since some processes uses a so called `BaseAddress` or `StartAddress`. And in my case the size of this BaseAddress is random from time to time.
As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045864/python-how-to-get-the-start-base-address-of-a-process) I tried using the following code:

```
BaseAddress = win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)
```

All it does is giving the same hex value over and over again, even though I for sure know that my BaseAddress have changed.

Screenshot from the linked thread showing what Im looking for (where the left part is the baseaddress):
[image: CE BaseAddress]

Comment: Ever figure out the answer to your question? I'm looking for the answer myself.

Comment: @DreamLane Nope, still haven't found anything. Decided to go with c# instead. Such a shame, since I love python.

Comment: I've been debating changing to C++ or C# as well. Python is awesome for prototyping though....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did manage to find a solution for python 3.5 32-bit and 64 bit.

For 32 bit I used psutil and pymem (as already suggested on this question).:

```
import psutil
import pymem

my_pid = None
pids = psutil.pids()
for pid in pids:
    ps = psutil.Process(pid)
    # find process by .exe name, but note that there might be more instances of solitaire.exe
    if "solitaire.exe" in ps.name():
        my_pid = ps.pid
        print( "%s running with pid: %d" % (ps.name(), ps.pid) )

base_address = pymem.process.base_address(pid)
```

For 64 bit pymem was not working. I found suggestions using win32api.GetModuleHandle(fileName) but it required win32api.LoadLibrary(fileName) which was not using an already running process.

Therefore I found this suboptimal solution, since this returns a whole list of possibilities:

```
import win32process
import win32api

# first get pid, see the 32-bit solution

PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF
processHandle = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, my_pid)
modules = win32process.EnumProcessModules(processHandle)
processHandle.close()
base_addr = modules[0] # for me it worked to select the first item in list...
```

Comment: From where pid's are coming from in first snippet?

Answer (score 0):

See [How to enumerate modules in python 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763459/how-to-enumerate-modules-in-python-64bit) for some good code to use. You are looking for 'modBaseAddr'.

For more info on tagMODULEENTRY32, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684225(v=vs.85).aspx

You could also use [pymem](https://github.com/srounet/Pymem) ('obsolete' project but still works) with the following code (you want modBaseAddr):

```
  for m in self.listModules():
    if m.szModule==szModule:
      print m.szModule, m.szExePath, m.modBaseAddr
```

Comment: With pymem it works to do base_address = pymem.process.base_address(pid) but the MODULEENTRY32 class that you link to does not work - it returns a different modeBaseAddr every time you run it and it's wrong.