# i am playing with processes etc. but I dont know how to add "client.dll" to hex value

Tags: python-3.x, process, reverse-engineering

In cheat engine you can do "client.dll"+00D3AC5C and in reclass <client.dll>+00D3AC5C

how to do the same in python I am using ReadWriteMemory but I will soon change it for something more complex. Can you tell me please how to do it with RWM or with something other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/vsantiago113/ReadWriteMemory/blob/e8b2859349e41380b561f6115ee43f058323877a/ReadWriteMemory/__init__.py#L20) of that library, there's seemingly no way to get the base address of a process.

However you can get the base address by bypassing the library and doing it yourself via [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027459/finding-the-baseaddress-of-a-running-process). Then, once you have the hex value of the base address, you can then simply add an offset to it, then use RWM's `read()` or `get_pointer()`.