# Read Write Memory Multi-Level Pointer with offsets not working as intended

Tags: python, memory

```
from ReadWriteMemory import ReadWriteMemory

rwm = ReadWriteMemory()

process = rwm.get_process_by_name('AoE2DE_s.exe')
process.open()

villagerPointer = process.get_pointer('AoE2DE_s.exe+2BFCA10', offsets=[0x18, 0x4*0x2+0x9228])

villagerCount = process.read(villagerPointer)

print (villagerCount)
```

Always returning 0 but should be returning 119. Used cheat engine to find the pointer and offsets, but can't replicate it in Python. Super frustrated, I couldn't get anything to work.

[image: Pointer]

Comment: What's the exact pointer in Cheat Engine? Also, are you certain that the pointer will always point to the memory location you want? As in, can you definitely read that value with Cheat Engine using your pointer every time, and get the result you want?

Comment: The pointer is static so I am certain it will stay in the location. I edited the post to include the pointer in Cheat Engine.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the string value `'AoE2DE_s.exe+2BFCA10'` to `get_pointer()`, but that's apparently not a valid input, according to the [source code](https://github.com/vsantiago113/ReadWriteMemory/blob/e8b2859349e41380b561f6115ee43f058323877a/ReadWriteMemory/__init__.py#L78) of the library you're using. You have to actually pass the hex value of that address. So, I'd get the base address of the .exe first, then add that hex value, but again, you ultimately have to pass only a hex address to `read()` or `get_pointer()`.

The reason you aren't getting any errors is just because that library isn't doing much input validation; hence the "garbage in, garbage out" concept applies.

Edit: According to the source code of that library, there's seemingly no way to get the base address of a process.

However you can get the base address by bypassing the library and doing it yourself via [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027459/finding-the-baseaddress-of-a-running-process). Then, once you have the hex value of the base address, you can then simply add an offset to it, then use RWM's `read()` or `get_pointer()`.